# How to escape single quote in XML SQL SERVER

Tags: sql-server, xml, t-sql

I have this query

`select '''' FOR XML PATH('ROW'), type;`

and the result is `<ROW>'</ROW>` , but i want the result to be `<ROW>&apos;</ROW>`, and i don t want to use replace function. I'm using SQL Server 2014

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQL Server is not entity encoding single apostrophe.